# How to replace every font with a custom on in a Github Page?

Tags: html, css, github

I've overwritten style in `docs/assets/css/style.css` like this:

```
---
---

@import "{{ site.theme }}";
@import "fonts";

header {
  display: none;
}

body {
 font-family: 'CaptureSmallz'; 
}
```

In `docs/assets/fonts` I added the file `Capsmall.ttf`.
In `docs/_sass/fonts.scss` I put

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'CaptureSmallz';
   src: url('../fonts/Capsmall.ttf') format('truetype');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;

}
```

But this doesn't seem to overwrite anything and I get no build-error-message either.
What did I miss here?

// EDIT: It works with normal text but doesnt cover headers etc.
Is there a way to overwrite all fonts at once?

// EDIT 2: I'm now doing it like this:

```
---
---

@import "{{ site.theme }}";
@import "fonts";

* {
 font-family: 'CaptureSmallz' !important; 
}

h1 {
 font-family: 'CaptureSmallz' !important;
}
```

and it works, but I think this is far from ideal.